# To put all the class attributes into a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a class like this one: (The name of the class: Man)

> Name:"daniel" | numOfLegs: "5" | numOfHands: "7" | numOfEyes: "10" | numofHeads: "80" |
>   numofBrains: "2"

I want to put all the attributes into one list but its very long code:

```
List<string> lst= new list<string>();
lst.Add(Man.numOfLegs);
lst.Add(Man.numOfHands);
......
```

The problem is that I have more than 80 attributes and it keeps growing.

*all the variables are string

> **the goal: {"daniel","5","7","1","80","2"}**

Help me please :(

Comment: If your class has 80 fields, then I'd say you've probably got a design issue to start with... are you sure they shouldn't be split up more? (And are these static properties or instance properties? It would help if you'd show compilable sample code rather than pseudo-code.)

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<string, int>` where the key is the name of the property and the value is the count. For example: `var manCounts = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "Legs", 5 }, { "Hands", 7 } }; int countLegs = manCounts["Legs"];`

Comment: The human body contains alot of organs. I cant put here the original code because the code is long and i dont want people to see it.

Comment: Tim Schmelter, I looking for a code that do the "black job" for me. I know how to put the variables manualy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use refection for this:

```
var  man = new Man();
//fill man properties
foreach (var prop in man.GetType().GetProperties()) //use man.GetType().GetFields() for fields
{
    lst.Add(prop.GetValue(man));
}
```

Is that OK for you?